# X11, sending an event with XSendEvent(3)

Tags: c, linux, x11, xterm, motif

I embedded a X11 app (xterm) in a Motif window.  All seems to work fine, but if I press a key when the pointer isn't above the embedded app, it doesn't get it.  Trying to fix this, I changed the main loop of the main app. Now it's like this:

```
  XEvent ev;
  for (;;)
    {
      XtAppNextEvent (app, &ev);

      /* If the event is a keypress, send it to
       * the xterm window. Else, dispatch it.
       */
      Window *xtW = NULL, parent, _root;
      unsigned int noC;

      if (ev.type == KeyPress || ev.type == KeyRelease)
   {
#ifdef DEBUG
     fprintf (stderr, "Key event\n");
#endif
     while (xtW == NULL)
       XQueryTree (XtDisplay (drawW), XtWindow (drawW), &_root,
         &parent, &xtW, &noC);

     XSendEvent (XtDisplay (drawW), *xtW, True,
            (KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask), &ev);
     XFlush (XtDisplay (drawW));
#ifdef DEBUG
     fprintf (stderr, "sent key event\n");
#endif
   }
      else
     XtDispatchEvent (&ev);
    }
```

When I press a key outside embedded xterm the debug line being printed, but xterm
doesn't print the key I sent.

How can I fix this?  If needed, I'll post the code.

--mghis

Comment: You should at least set `ev.Window` to the correct value.

Comment: Gcc says ev has no member window (nor Window).  If you mean `ev.xkey.window`, I tried with `ev.xkey.window = *xtW;` and the app still doesn't get the key.

Comment: Yes, ev is actually a union, it has no `window` member, but all of the union members do. So you're right about the `ev.xkey.window` syntax. You also should specifically enable `xterm` to accept events sent with `XSendEvent`, by setting its `allowSendEvents` resource to `True`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! **It works!** Setting that resource did it! **Thanks** a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Well to start with you are assuming the `XQueryTree` will only return one child window - maybe it is returning more than one and you are passing the event on to the wrong one?

I'm not sure what that while loop around the `XQueryTree` call is for either.

You should also be calling `XFree` to free the child window list once you're done with it, or you will be leaking memory.

Comment: There is only one window in drawW.  This is for sure and I use the same `XQueryTree` function to resize that window.  The while loop is needed because the embedded window starts a bit after the main window, in another thread.  With while loop, I'm sure embedded app is started and `XQueryTree` found it.  Thanks for `XFree`, I added it.  What about `XSendEvent` problem?

Comment: Well have you checked that none of the X calls are returning an error? See also the comment on your question about setting the target window in the event.

Comment: I answered the comment. I verified the X calls with `assert()` but the calls return 0.